# Nested SliverPersistentHeaders scroll behind parent SliverPersistentHeader

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

So i would like to have a page with first some content, then two tabs with two different lists. The Tab bar should behave like a PersistentHeader (sticking to the top). One of these Lists within the TabBarView also contains SliverPersistentHeaders but these do not stack up on the TabBar PersistentHeader but scroll behind instead. How can one achieve such behaviour?

Here's a gif that shows the current behaviour:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/OEa49K4]

This is what i've tried so far:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return NestedScrollView(
                    controller: _scrollViewController,
                    headerSliverBuilder: 
                (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
                      return <Widget>[
                        SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                            _buildTopImage(),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: defaultPagePadding),
                              child: _buildTopText(),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ),
                        SliverAppBar(
                          pinned: true,
                          floating: true,
                          expandedHeight: 0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          bottom: TabBar(
                            labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                            tabs: <Widget>[
                              Tab(
                                text: "Tab 1",
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                text: "Tab 2",
                              )
                            ],
                            controller: _tabController,
                          ),
                        )
                      ];
                    },
                    body: TabBarView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildList1(),
                        _buildList2(),
                      ],
                      controller: _tabController,
                    ),
                  ),
}

Widget _buildList2() {
  return CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text('Test'),
          ),
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text('Test'),
          ),
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text('Test'),
          ),
]);
}
```

I'm new to Flutter so i would really appreciate any help from you guys!